# Acessing machines on the same domain and update software automatically?

Tags: winforms

I have built a windows application in .net and installed the application on client machine through set up and deployment project. The software is installed on around 15 machines which are on the same domain. We keep adding new features as per client suggestions. The problem is I have to reinstall the software on all the machines every time the software is updated.

I am looking for solution for the above problem something like if I place updated version on common machine and set up is updated on all the machines from common location. I have storing version number in application config file and I increment the version by 1 number each time version is updated. I am thinking to create new table in database which will have latest version number. When ever version is changed in database, an .exe will be executed which will update the software on all the machines from common machine.

How can i do that? If anyone has better way of doing that then please let me know.

FYI: I have already checked click once but it does not meet my requirements as it updates software for one user only and I have to update the software for all the users.

Thanks

Comment: You have a *client-installed* application written in *ASP.NET*?  Either you're confusing the terminology, or you're done something terribly wrong here.  If it's an ASP.NET application, I would think it would be deployed to a web server and all users would use it from that server.  Updates would then be trivial, since you'd just need to re-deploy to the web server.

Comment: In such situations, ClickOnce has always worked for me perfectly because once i publish a new version of the application, clients accessing the application will always pick the latest updates on application startup. PLUS, you can also set the minimum required version.

Comment: It is asp.net windows application and used set up and deployment project to make application installable.

Comment: @user2515685 there is no such thing as an ASP.NET WinForms application, you mean it's a **.NET WinForms** application. The ASP part stands for *active server pages* and is a web technology built on top of the .NET framework.

Comment: How big is the domain in general? Larger organizations will tend to use e.g. [Configuration Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Configuration_Manager) to control rollouts, or use Group Policy. Smaller organizations might have a login script that attempts to install the latest version on every login (but that does depend on the users having sufficient privileges). Either way, it tends to stop being a software issue and become more of an organizational/IT one.

Comment: Domain has about 30 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple form with a button and on the click event you can try the following code.
You can use this techniques to update any files related to your software that you want to update.

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError = true)]

    public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        IntPtr admin_token = default(IntPtr);

        WindowsIdentity wid_current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        WindowsIdentity wid_admin = null;

        WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;

        try

        {

            if (LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", 9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)

            {

                wid_admin = new WindowsIdentity(admin_token);

                wic = wid_admin.Impersonate();

                System.IO.File.Copy("D:\\test.txt", "\\\\\\192.168.25.40\\c$\\D:\\test.txt", true);



                MessageBox.Show("Copy succeeded");

            }

            else

            {

                MessageBox.Show("Copy Failed");

            }

        }

        catch (System.Exception se)

        {

            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString(), "Error code: " + ret.ToString());

            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);

        }

        finally

        {

            if (wic != null)

            {

                wic.Undo();

            }

        }

    }
```